# How to prove the following formula is a constant?

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, transcendental-numbers, constants

For any $\rho\in\mathbb{R}^+$, prove that the following formula equals a constant:

$$\dfrac{1}{\rho^2}{\int_{-\rho}^\rho x^2 e^{\left(\tfrac{\rho^2}{x^2-\rho^2}\right)}dx}\left({\int_{-\rho}^\rho e^{\left(\tfrac{\rho^2}{x^2-\rho^2}\right)}dx}\right)^{-1}=\text{constant}$$

The constant can be easily verified as about 0.158..., but how to prove it?

Can we obtain a radical form of the constant? Is it a transcendental number?

Comment: Usually, you can prove $f(x)$ is a constant function by showing that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: what if you change variable in the integrals and let $x=\rho y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's change variables in the integral: $x=\rho y$, $dx = \rho dy$:
$$
\dfrac{1}{\rho^2}{\int_{-\rho}^\rho x^2e^\tfrac{\rho^2}{x^2-\rho^2}dx}\left({\int_{-\rho}^\rho e^\tfrac{\rho^2}{x^2-\rho^2}dx}\right)^{-1}=
\dfrac{1}{\rho^2}{\int_{-1}^1 \rho^2 y^2e^\tfrac{1}{y^2-1}\rho dy}\left({\int_{-1}^1 e^\tfrac{1}{y^2-1}\rho dy}\right)^{-1}=
{\int_{-1}^1 e^\tfrac{1}{y^2-1} dy}\left({\int_{-1}^1 y^2 e^\tfrac{1}{y^2-1} dy}\right)^{-1}
$$

**added:**
However it is apparent that the integral is not convergent.

Comment: thank you! I think I made a mistake in it. I have updated it. Is it possible to make it clear what the constant is or its properties?